# How to use Cache-Control and Expires headers in Java Server Pages

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, cache-control

I ran my site in PageSpeed.
It tells me:

> Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static
>   resources instructs the browser to load previously downloaded
>   resources from local disk rather than over the network.

I tried to implement it according to what they say at https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching, and in some other ways.

But, so far I didn't succeed. Maybe someone can help me how to do it.

I prefer to keep only the images in the cache.

Anyway I would love to know how I can manage saving and not saving files in the cache

My site is being developed with the Google Application Engine and Java Server Pages.

Answer (score 2):

`Cache-Control` is a [HTTP Header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) that controls caching between the server and client.  It is set using the `HttpServletResponse` like this:

```
httpResponse.addHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=60");
```

Where `60` is the number of seconds to cache for.